# Getting org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 errror in Android App

Tags: java, android, json

I have tried all answers given for "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 " before my question ,

but not getting correct way for my app, please help me ,

Log

```
08-22 10:59:45.112: I/System.out(6677): .....reader.readLine()..........  [{"m_id":1,"send_id":1,"user_name_from":"mahi ","user_imei_from":"356605052523574","message":"mahi","time_date":"2014-08-21 05:32:15 PM","item":null,"qty":null,"image":null,"user_name_to":"demo","user_imei_to":"000000000000000"}]
08-22 10:59:45.122: W/System.err(6677): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-22 10:59:45.122: W/System.err(6677):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-22 10:59:45.132: W/System.err(6677):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-22 10:59:45.132: W/System.err(6677):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-22 10:59:45.132: W/System.err(6677):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-22 10:59:45.132: W/System.err(6677):     at com.pis.pisservices.AllMessageService$sync.doInBackground(AllMessageService.java:167)
08-22 10:59:45.152: W/System.err(6677):     at com.pis.pisservices.AllMessageService$sync.doInBackground(AllMessageService.java:1)
08-22 10:59:45.152: W/System.err(6677):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-22 10:59:45.152: W/System.err(6677):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-22 10:59:45.152: W/System.err(6677):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-22 10:59:45.152: W/System.err(6677):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-22 10:59:45.162: W/System.err(6677):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-22 10:59:45.162: W/System.err(6677):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-22 10:59:45.162: W/System.err(6677):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

In Activity

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet getrequest= new HttpGet(SERVICE_URL);

                try
                {
                    System.out.println("..........sync...All msg..Service...In try........");
                    HttpResponse response=client.execute(getrequest);
                    System.out.println("....jsdata.response..."+response);
                    InputStream jsdata= response.getEntity().getContent();
                    System.out.println("....jsdata.InputStream..."+jsdata);
                    BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsdata));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    System.out.println(".....reader.readLine().........."+reader.readLine());

                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        builder.append(line);
                        System.out.println("....builder.append(line);..."+builder.append(line));
                    }
                    String Jsondata=builder.toString();

                    JSONArray item=new JSONArray(Jsondata);
//                      System.out.println(".....JSONArray..item...."+item);

                    int temp=item.length();

                    System.out.println("...All msg.temp...."+temp);

                    if(item != null)
                    {
                        Cursor cur = dbh.getblankIdCUR();

                        System.out.println("...dbh.getblankIdCUR()....."+dbh.getblankIdCUR());
                        for(int i = 0; i < item.length(); i++){
                        if(i<temp)
                        {
                            JSONObject c = item.getJSONObject(i);
                            String m_id =c.getString(TAGm_id);
                            String send_id =c.getString(TAG_send_id);
                            String from_name =c.getString(TAGfrom_name);
                            String from_imei = c.getString(TAGfrom_imei);
                            String msg = c.getString(TAGMessage);
                            String msg_img = c.getString(TAGmsg_image);
                            String m_item=c.getString(TAGitem);
                            String Qty = c.getString(TAGQty);
                            String time_date = c.getString(TAGtime_date);
                            String to_imei = c.getString(TAGto_imei);
                            String to_name = c.getString(TAGto_name);

                            String Unique_id = from_imei + time_date;


                            System.out.println("......All msg..Service....sdds...........");
                            System.out.println("...msg..cur.getCount() ..........."+cur.getCount() );

                    // update the sent message
                        if(cur.getCount() != 0)
                        {   System.out.println("........Service...ssssssssssss............");
                            cur.moveToFirst();
                                do {

                                    int snd=cur.getInt(1);
                                    String s= Integer.toString(snd);
                                    System.out.println("........send_id.equalsIgnoreCase(s)...fdf........"+send_id.equalsIgnoreCase(s));

                                    if(send_id.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                                    {
                                    System.out.println("........send_id.equalsIgnoreCase(s)..........."+send_id.equalsIgnoreCase(s));
                                        dbh.updatemessage(from_imei,send_id,m_id,time_date);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } while (cur.moveToNext());
                        }

//                          get messages which has been send by other
                        else if((send_id.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) && ((!from_imei.equalsIgnoreCase(Imei_no)) || (from_imei.equalsIgnoreCase(Imei_no))))
                        {
                            dbh.Insert_msgdata(m_id,send_id, from_name, from_imei, msg, msg_img, m_item, Qty, time_date, to_imei, to_name);

                            showNotification(from_name);        
                        }
                        // get all messages which after data clear
                        else
                        {

                            dbh.Insert_msgdata(m_id,send_id, from_name, from_imei, msg, msg_img, m_item, Qty, time_date, to_imei, to_name);
                        }
                        }
                        }

                    }






} 
                        catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
        }
```

Jason String

[{"m_id":1,"send_id":1,"user_name_from":"mahi ","user_imei_from":"356605052523574","message":"mahi","time_date":"2014-08-21 05:32:15 PM","item":null,"qty":null,"image":null,"user_name_to":"demo","user_imei_to":"000000000000000"}]

1. My jason is not getting null , means it has some values.
2. I have tried this on Locally But not done.
3. I have used Get Method.

So , Please Help Me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: This line in the logcat: `at com.pis.pisservices.AllMessageService$sync.doInBackground(AllMessageService.java:167)` shows that the error occurs at line 167 in your `AllMessageService.java` file. Update your question with an indication of this particular line.

Comment: Provide your JSON string

Comment: Provided Code is of same file...The error line is as......JSONArray item=new JSONArray(Jsondata);

Comment: [{"m_id":1,"send_id":1,"user_name_from":"mahi ","user_imei_from":"356605052523574","message":"mahi","time_date":"2014-08-21 05:32:15 PM","item":null,"qty":null,"image":null,"user_name_to":"demo","user_imei_to":"000000000000000"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
String line;
System.out.println(".....reader.readLine().........."+reader.readLine());

while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
{
  builder.append(line);
  System.out.println("....builder.append(line);..."+builder.append(line));
}
```

to

```
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
{
  System.out.println(".....reader.readLine().........."+ line);
  builder.append(line);
  System.out.println("....builder.append(line);..."+builder.append(line));
}
```

otherwise you are reading the line, printing it and throwing it away, and will not be added to the jsonData variable

Comment: Now it not showing error but....log as....08-22 11:55:38.332: I/System.out(12967): .....reader.readLine()..........[]
08-22 11:55:38.332: I/System.out(12967): ....builder.append(line);...[][]

Comment: well maybe you `poted` it wrong, just trying to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59788/discussion-between-anupamaj-and-scary-wombat).

Comment: My bad, I though a chat was something done real time.  I waited 15 minutes, but you did not show.